# My Email To Form is not working on mobile device

Tags: php, forms, email, mobile

I have an email to form, this works fine on a desktop but doesn't work using a mobile device as in it says it sent but isn't coming through to emails, I'm guessing it's because the phone doesn't possibly click on send form button in the HTML? I was hoping for some help please which would be much appriatied

So from the HTML page, I have the submit button

```
<div class="submitForm">
    <button type="submit" name="contact_query" class="submit_query" onClick="gtag_report_conversion()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

at the bottom of the HTML file, I have a script that opens a PHP script file and leaves a message to the user

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var formdata = $('form').serialize()
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'formDataBad.php',
        data: {formData:formdata,form:'home'},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);

        var message = '<div id="stage" class="form-all" style="    margin-top: 100px;"><p style="text-align:center;"><img src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/img/check-icon.png" alt="" width="128" height="128"></p><div style="text-align:center;"><h1 style="text-align:center;">Thank You!</h1><p style="text-align:center;">Your submission has been received.</p><p style="text-align:center;">One of our friendly team will contact you shortly to discuss your application.&nbsp;</p></div> </div>';
        
            $('article.box.post').html(message);                            
         
         document.getElementById("queryForm").reset();
        }
      });
      
    });                
  });
</script>
```

This then opens the php script file which has this below

```
<?php
$data = explode('&',$_POST['formData']);
$to = 'info@domain.uk,domain@gmail.com';

if($_POST['form'] == 'home'){
    $firstname = explode('=',$data[0]);
    $lastname = explode('=',$data[1]);
    $email = explode('=',$data[2]);
    $phone = explode('=',$data[3]);
    $alternative_number = explode('=',$data[4]);
    $house_number = explode('=',$data[5]);
    $street_address = explode('=',$data[6]);
    /*$street_address2 = explode('=',$data[6]);
    $city = explode('=',$data[7]);*/
    $postcode = explode('=',$data[7]);
    $home_owner = explode('=',$data[8]);
    
    $loan_amount = explode('=',$data[9]);
    $mortgage = explode('=',$data[10]);
    $secured_loan = explode('=',$data[11]);
    $property_value = explode('=',$data[12]);
    /*$question = explode('=',$data[14]);*/
    
    $message = '<html>
                <head>
                <style>
                table, th, td {
                  border: 1px solid black;
                  border-collapse: collapse;
                }
                th, td {
                  padding: 5px;
                  text-align: left;    
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                 <table style="width:60%">
                  <tr>
                    <th>First Name:</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($firstname[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($lastname[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($email[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($phone[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>Alternate Number</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($alternative_number[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>House Number</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($house_number[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                   <tr>
                    <th>Street Address</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($street_address[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>Post Code</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($postcode[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>Homeowner ?</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($home_owner[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                  
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>Loan Amount</th>
                    <td>&#163; '.urldecode($loan_amount[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>Mortgage</th>
                    <td>&#163; '.urldecode($mortgage[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>Secured Loan</th>
                    <td>&#163; '.urldecode($secured_loan[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                  <th>Property Value</th>
                    <td>&#163; '.urldecode($property_value[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                   
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>';
    
    $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'From: '.urldecode($firstname[1]).' <'.urldecode($email[1]).'>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
    
    $sendemail = mail($to,"Lender App",$message,$headers);
    if($sendemail){
        print_r("TRUE");
    }else{
        print_r("FALSE");
    }
} else if($_POST['form'] == 'contact'){
    $fullname = explode('=',$data[0]);
    $email = explode('=',$data[1]);
    $telephone = explode('=',$data[2]);
    $query = explode('=',$data[3]);
    
    $message = '<html>
                <head>
                <style>
                table, th, td {
                  border: 1px solid black;
                  border-collapse: collapse;
                }
                th, td {
                  padding: 5px;
                  text-align: left;    
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                 <table style="width:60%">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Fullname:</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($fullname[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                 
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($email[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>
                
                  <tr>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($telephone[1]).'</td>
                  </tr>  
                
                   <tr>
                   <th>Query</th>
                    <td>'.urldecode($query[1]).'</td>
                  </tr> 
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>';
    
    $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'From: '.urldecode($fullname[1]).' <'.urldecode($email[1]).'>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
    
    $sendemail = mail($to,"Contact Query",$message,$headers);
    if($sendemail){
        echo "TRUE";
    } else {
        echo "FALSE";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe because you are mixing FormData and Serialize ? [Check the way to create a FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Comment: _“I'm guessing it's because the phone doesn't possibly click on send form button in the HTML?”_ - I’m guessing, “the desktop” does not do that either. Can you please explain what that is supposed to _mean_?

Comment: Grasping at straws a bit here, but does the mobile browser you are using have javascript enabled?